# How to slice strings in a dataframe by finding another strings location and the location value differs in each row?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have a dataframe column "df_weather[0]",like the following (strings are very long)

```py
S.No,Values,
452,"temperature":83.0,
514,current "temperature":81.0,
653,new modified "temperature":89.0,
```

I want to extract the values after the string temperature. ie 83.0, 81.0 and 89.0

for this I found the location of the string "temperature" and stored all the three values into a list. Now the list has three locations.

Second, I tried to slice the string by taking each member in a list

```py
list_weather = df_weather[1].str.find('"temperature":').tolist()
list_temp=[]

for member in list_weather:
        list_temp.append(df_weather[1].str.slice(member+14,member+18))
```

but the last line takes the first value in the list "list_weather" (ie 14 as temperature is 12 characters long) and slices the full dataframe three times. Returns three sets, 
first line has correct value, the second and third are not correct in each set.

ie "list_temp" has 83.0, ratu, temp (three sets).

Comment: does this work: `df.Values.str.extract(r'(?:"temperature":)(\d+)',expand=False)` ?

Comment: it does. partially. Missed the first line. got the second and third. And it couldn't get the value if the values are enclosed in quotes. Thank you anky_91 for giving the idea. Its so simpler than what I thought.

Comment: That is because the first value does not have quotes enclosing `temperature`. :) `"`

Comment: Is python missing quotes if it starts at 0? it has quotes.

Comment: can there be any other number in the series other than the value for temperature?

Comment: yes there are lot more. But your code gets the required values, only the first is missing, if I add a character in the first line before "temperature" it works. Any how thank you for the idea. I am started learning Regex.

Comment: in that case either `df.Values.str.extract(r'(?:"temperature":|temperature:)(\d+)',expand=False)` or `df.Values.str.extract(r'(?::)(\d+)',expand=False)` will solve it. :)